# Terminal scrolling from shell script

Tags: command-line, terminal, shell, scrolling, tty

Is there any way to perform the effect of using the scroll bar in Terminal.app using a shell command? Maybe something cross-platform, that works in Linux terminal emulators too?

Answer (score 0):

> using a shell command

Yes, but *only if* it's provided by terminal emulator itself.

Comment: Do you know of any terminal emulators that provide such a command?

Comment: @beardtree no, I don't. Perhaps [Final Term](http://finalterm.org/) can do this?